# Firebase issue logging in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So for my react web app I am using Firebase and email/password verification. Yesterday everything worked great, but now every time I try to log in I am getting "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." I even tried using the version I had yesterday from GitHub and I get the same error so I'm really not sure what to do. The only thing I did between now and then was try to host the app on firebase using firebase init/deploy. I'm assuming that has somehow messed up my whole thing, and I don't know how to fix what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the domain of the firebase app in the firebase console.
This is the first result I got into google:

[cant-sign-up-with-firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774595/cant-sign-up-with-firebase)