# Frequent "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase anon login to authenticate certain parts of our API.
This error "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." seems to pop up frequently with no apparent pattern.

This seems to happen in all types of browsers. Mobile, tablet or desktop but I can't for the life of me reproduce this error.
I've tried many different types of physical devices as well as Browserstack.

Some have suggested that users experiencing this aren't allowing Javascript or have some kind of browser extension preventing Firebase to work correctly. I find that hard to believe since this keeps happening very frequently. (Also I've never met a person in my whole career that has Javascript disabled).

I initialize Firebase like so in my React's index entry point.

```
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    // ... config setup
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
    .catch((error) => {
        bugsnag.notify(error);
});
```

I'm using React 16.8.6 and Firebase 5.9.4.

Error seems to be originating in google-closure-library:

```
../node_modules/google-closure-library/closure/goog/async/nexttick.js:41:44
```

[image]

I'm hoping users aren't affected by this error but I have no idea if they are.

Comment: Are you using <form> tag ? You might found some fix here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774595/cant-sign-up-with-firebase

Comment: @ClémentRousseau Nope. Not using form. This question is not similar to mine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052162/firebase-authentication-firebasenetworkexception-a-network-error-such-as-timeo Maybe one of the fixes there might help?

Comment: @MauriceNino I'm afraid they don't explain this in my case. Firebase seems to be working correctly. We have thousands of anon logins per day. We get many error logs like this every day but still no complaints from customers. I'm not sure if this is affecting the users.. maybe this is a Bugsnag bug?

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this issue(my issue) pausing my Kaspersky anti-virus. I found some other answers saying the html form tag caused this.